# Best practice for Vue.JS + Node.js backend in ONE SINGLE Heroku pod?

Tags: node.js, rest, heroku, vue.js, vuejs2

[This blog post I found today](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/) shows something like this for React. He  starts with a node project and then within that he creates a react project in a subfolder. Plus some proxy config stuff.

I wasn't this clever about 10 days ago but here's what I did for Vue.

1. Created a Vue project
2. Built it for production
3. Added a package.json and a server.js in the `dist` folder created by the Vue build process
4. The package.json contains these two lines: `"postinstall": "npm install express"` and `"start": "node server.js"`

And voilá! Express listens on 8081 internally (but translated to 80/443 by Heroku) and I can get a response in the Vue frontend from the Node backend. So technically it works. But I don't feel it's a nice solution. Kind of messy, smells like desperate hacking and tinkering.

The point is, of course, to avoid having two different Heroku pods for an otherwise small, almost weightless personal project. One for the frontend part and one for the backend.

Can you show me anything better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [vue-cli project](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

Then you create a subfolder with your express project and start your script (in package json) like :

`npm run vueproject && npm run expressproject`

and your both projects will start together.

You have to :

- Use a different port for each project.
- Install dependencies of the *expressproject* in the
  *vueproject* package.
- Know that's not a good practice to do like this.

Comment: So basically it's not recommended, if you insist to do it then follow the same pattern as in the linked article with React. But the perfect solution would be to have the frontend and the backend separated. Right?

Comment: Right, you should create a single project like an API, and a second project (or more) like an UI